# Removing data sources from a PowerBI gateway

Tags: microsoft-powerbi

It appears that it is currently impossible to remove a data source from a PowerBI gateway - is this actually true, or am I missing some obscure option somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is very poor UI design, but there is actually a small, light-grey "..." button to the right of each Data Source entry. It pops up a menu with a REMOVE option.

[image]

Comment: wow, not only is it almost the same colour as the background, it only appears once you hover your mouse exactly where it appears! thanks!